# Refresh RecyclerView from BroadcastReceiver When TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING

Tags: java, android

I have a tabLayout in which there is Log Fragment tab it store all the incoming calls details in LogsData List Object and set .
New callLogs is updated after App close and restart but I want to refresh my RecyclerView when the call is in ringing state.

My **LogFragment**

```
public class LogsFragment extends Fragment {
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private ListAdapter mListadapter;
ArrayList data;
TinyDB tinyDB;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_call_log, container, false);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    tinyDB = new TinyDB(getContext());
    data = tinyDB.getListObject("LogData", LogsData.class);

    final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    data = tinyDB.getListObject("LogData", LogsData.class);

    mListadapter = new ListAdapter(data);
    mListadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mListadapter);

    return view;
}
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onMyEvent(Object o) {
    /* Refresh your adapter */

    data = tinyDB.getListObject("LogData", LogsData.class);

    mListadapter = new ListAdapter(data);
    mListadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mListadapter);
};
public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<LogsData> dataList;

    public ListAdapter(ArrayList<LogsData> data) {
        this.dataList = data;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textViewName;
        TextView textViewNumb;
        TextView textViewTime;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.textViewName =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.cName);
            this.textViewNumb =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.number);
            this.textViewTime =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.time_stamp);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ListAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.log_list, parent, false);

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.textViewName.setText(dataList.get(position).getName());
        holder.textViewNumb.setText(dataList.get(position).getNumber());
        holder.textViewTime.setText(dataList.get(position).getTime());
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item " + position + " is clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataList.size();
    }
    @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    public void onMyEvent(Object o) {
        /* Refresh your adapter */

        data = tinyDB.getListObject("LogData", LogsData.class);

        mListadapter = new ListAdapter(data);
        mListadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mListadapter);
    };
}
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}
```

}

And my **PhoneStateReceiver** Class

```
public class PhoneStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public final static String TAG = "SSD";

String incomingNumber;
String state;
DateFormat timeFormat;
Context context;
String date;
String cName;
ArrayList data;


@SuppressLint("UnsafeProtectedBroadcastReceiver")
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    TinyDB tinydb = new TinyDB(context);
    data = tinydb.getListObject("LogData", LogsData.class);

    try {
        state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        cName = getContactName(incomingNumber, context);
        timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy, HH:mm");
        date = timeFormat.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        Log.d(TAG, date);

        String phoneState = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

        if (phoneState.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            data.add(new LogsData(cName, incomingNumber, date));
            tinydb.putListObject("LogData", data);
            Toast.makeText(context, date + " " + incomingNumber + " " + cName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }





 EventBus.getDefault().post(new Object());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public String getContactName(final String phoneNumber, Context context) {
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));

    String[] projection = new String[]{ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME};

    String contactName = "";
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            contactName = cursor.getString(0);
        }
        cursor.close();
    }

    return contactName;

}
```

}

I update my codes please see it.

Comment: Do you receive Intent when the phone is in ringing state (Inside your Receiver) ?

Comment: Yes It's shows the Toast Notification when phone is ringing

Comment: You can notifyDataSetChanged inside the Receiver . Did not see your code though . Have you done that ?

Comment: How can i set notifyDataSetChanged inside the Receiver.

Comment: Well there are many possibilities. But it depends how much you are willing to change your code base.  You should have access to Your Adapter instance inside your Receiver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`EventBus`** to do it
In your `LogsFragment` prepare subscriber like this:

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)  
public void onMyEvent(Object o) {
    /* Refresh your adapter */

    data = tinyDB.getListObject("LogData", LogsData.class);

    mListadapter = new ListAdapter(data);
    mListadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mListadapter);
};
```

And in your `PhoneStateReceiver` call your subscriber like this:

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new Object());
```

Do not forget to `register` and `unregister` your subscriber in `LogsFragment`
You can read more about `EventBus` in [here](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

Comment: @Ankit what is the problem? Did you add register to your fragment onStart method?

Comment: yes i add both mehod `@Override
 public void onStart() {
     super.onStart();
     EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
 }

 @Override
 public void onStop() {
     super.onStop();
     EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
 }`

Comment: @Ankit I edited my answer in post. Check post with `EventBus.getDefault().post(new Object());`